# Cypress assert item in table related to it's title

Tags: cypress, ag-grid

On my page I have multiple tables with this structure:

```
<div class="box"><h4>Service 1</h4></div>
<div class="container"><ag-grid-table>items in the table</ag-grid-table><div>

<div class="box"><h4>Service 2</h4>
<div class="container"><ag-grid-table>items in the table</ag-grid-table><div>
</div>

<div class="scope-header"><h5>Service 3</h5></div>
<div class="scope-grid"><ag-grid-table>items in the table</ag-grid-table><div>
```

As you can see, all sections have different structure, and there are even more on the page.

What I want to achieve is to assert that the **Service 3** table contains the correct item.

I was thinking about using `cy.get('div.scope-header').contains('Service 3')` and then using `next()` or `sibling()` but the `ag-grid-table` is neither directly next or sibling.

The only idea I have is to check `ag-grid-table:nth(n)`, this should work, but is there a solution  that selects the table according the header title text?

I mean select the table e.g. belonging to Service 3 only.

Comment: It would be good if you can add the original html structure of the `Service 3` and where the next element appears in the tree.

Comment: it is exactly as I wrote, after the header div there is a scope div and then the ag-grid table. It doesn't matter what structure the ag-grid table has (there are more divs in it), I will just assert if ag-grid table contains 'Text'. The problem is to select that ag-grid table which has the header Service 3. For now I solved it by cy.get('ag-grid-table:nth(5)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this with `.sibling()`

```js
cy.contains('div.scope-header', 'Service 3')
  .sibling('div.scope-grid')                  // move to specified sibling 
  .find('ag-grid-table')                      // within that element
  .should(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue from `cy.get('div.scope-header')`

```js
cy.contains('div.scope-header', 'Service 3')  // this returns div.scope-header 
                                              // not <h5>Service 3</h5> which 
                                              // cy.get().contains() would do
  .next()                                     // next() moves you to <div class="scope-grid">
  .find('ag-grid-table')                      // table is within that
```

Comment: Thank you all for brilliant answers, that's exactly what I had in my mind. Unfortunately I can accept only one answer, I'll go with one of the shortest one. Thanks to all!

Comment: cy.contains() is more powerful than you think and is definitely under used.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question, You can do something like this:

```js
cy.contains('div.scope-header', 'Service 3')
  .next() //goes to .scope-grid
  .within(() => {
    // scopes search within .scope-grid
    cy.contains('ag-grid-table', 'some text').should('be.visible')
    //OR
    cy.get('ag-grid-table').find('item selector').should('be.visible')
    //OR
    cy.get('ag-grid-table')
      .find('item selector')
      .should('have.text', 'some text')
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, you can do use [Traversal commands](https://example.cypress.io/commands/traversal).
Adding selectors to `next()` and `sibling()` is more robust when page layout changes.

```js
cy.contains('h5', 'Service 3')
  .parent('div.scope-header')
  .next('div.scope-grid')
  .children('ag-grid-table')
  .find('div.ag-row').eq(2)
  ...
```